# Why does the same code in one file import a function, and in a different file the module of the same name?

Tags: pytest, python-import, python-packaging, relative-import

The same import statement `from mypackage._aux import is_error` has two different meanings in similar files:

- In [`_aux/foobar/_foobar.py`](https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable/blob/master/mypackage/_aux/foobar/_foobar.py) it imports the function `is_error` from [`_aux/is_error/_is_error.py`](https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable/blob/master/mypackage/_aux/is_error/_is_error.py).
- But in [`_aux/abbrev_testing/_abbrev_testing.py`](https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable/blob/master/mypackage/_aux/abbrev_testing/_abbrev_testing.py) it imports the whole module [`_aux/is_error`](https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable/tree/master/mypackage/_aux/is_error) instead.

The first is the expected behavior, because [`_aux/__init__.py`](https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable/blob/master/mypackage/_aux/__init__.py) contains `from .is_error._is_error import is_error`. (format `from .folder.file import function`)

When I run `pytest`, the two tests in [`_abbrev_testing_test.py`](https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable/blob/master/mypackage/_aux/abbrev_testing/_abbrev_testing_test.py) fail, because `is_error` is not the expected function. (`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`)

It works when I use the line that I would like to abbreviate with the new function:
[image]
This includes the test in [`_foobar_test.py`](https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable/blob/master/mypackage/_aux/foobar/_foobar_test.py) - so in [`_foobar.py`](https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable/blob/master/mypackage/_aux/foobar/_foobar.py) the *function* was imported.

But in `_abbrev_testing.py` the *module* was imported:
[image]

Does someone understand the difference between the two files? Should I have done this in a different way?

I would love to know if there is some logical rule that would have avoided this. (To me this just looks absurd and erratic.)

**Edit:** In both files it works, when I use a long import statement not relying on [`_aux/__init__.py`](https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable/blob/master/mypackage/_aux/__init__.py):

- short: `from mypackage._aux import is_error` (format `from _aux import function`)
- long: `from mypackage._aux.is_error._is_error import is_error`
  (format `from _aux.folder.file import function`)

<s>This question can be summarized as:
What in `_abbrev_testing.py` is sabotaging the `__init__.py`?</s>

**Edit 2:** Steps to reproduce:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ git clone https://github.com/watchduck/module_object_is_not_callable.git
me@ubuntu:~$ cd module_object_is_not_callable/
me@ubuntu:~/module_object_is_not_callable$ virtualenv -p python3 env
```

Open project with IDE.

```
(env) me@ubuntu:~/module_object_is_not_callable$ pip install pytest
(env) me@ubuntu:~/module_object_is_not_callable$ pytest
```

Comment: The leading underscores in package names make this very difficult to read unfortunately

Comment: Can you add the command line you use to run those tests (pycharm won't run them or will spit different errors like "attempted relative import above top level package")

Comment: I just cloned the GitHub project with the steps described in the second edit. It get the error seen in the second screenshot. Maybe you try to run it in `mypackage` instead of the wrapper around it (`my_package` in the screenshots or `module_object_is_not_callable` if you clone it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What in _abbrev_testing.py is sabotaging the **init**.py?

Gotcha - if you change:

```
from .is_error._is_error import is_error
from .abbrev_testing._abbrev_testing import abbrev_testing
from .foobar._foobar import foobar
```

in your init problem goes away. You were:

```
from .abbrev_testing._abbrev_testing import abbrev_testing
from .is_error._is_error import is_error
```

setting the is_error to the *function* "is_error" only *after* you imported .abbrev_testing._abbrev_testing - where the is_error is (correctly) already been imported as a module.

> Should I have done this in a different way?

Certainly. Do not name functions the same name as modules/packages. They are different things, so should have different names. Also - avoid similar repetitive names, and leading underscores. Makes code very difficult to read (so I opened many times the _abbrev_testing_errors.py cause it looked very similar to _abbrev_testing.py or _abbrev_testing_test.py) - reserve "test" for tests.
I say this in all seriousness - python's import system is complex but the complexity is due, cause it's a complex problem. Correct naming makes this complexity manageable.

Comment: You are right. The sequence of lines in `__init__.py` is the key. `_abbrev_testing_test.py` is a test - namely the one that fails.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: Moving the `foobar` line before the `is_error` line produces the same problem - i.e. `_foobar_test.py` will fail.